# Tikz with \includestandalone, problem in TeX Live 2017

Tags: tikz-pgf, include, standalone

I have a problem with tikz pictures. The problem occurred after installing the new “vanilla” release of TeX Live 2017 on Ubuntu 17.04. Everything worked fine on the older version 2016, and I didn’t have this problem. The 2016 version was not “vanilla” and it was installed from Ubuntu repositories.

I have a tikz picture script

> single_quadrant_switch.tex

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[>=latex]
    \draw[style=help lines] (0,0) (3,2);
  \tikzset{font=\large}
    \coordinate (vec3) at (0:5);
    \coordinate (vec4) at (90:5);
    \coordinate (vec5) at (270:5);
    \coordinate (vec6) at (180:5);

  \fill[lightgray!50!white] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
  \draw[->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec3);
    \draw[->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec4); 
    \draw[->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec5);
    \draw[->,very thick,black] (0,0) -- (vec6);
  \draw (5,-0.2) node [align=left, below] {Switch \\ off state \\ voltage};
  \draw (-0.2,4.9) node [align=left, left] {Switch \\ on state \\ current};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I create a pdf of the picture, it works fine.
The problem occurs when I want to include it in another file with the command \includestandalone
like this

```
\includestandalone[width=0.45\textwidth]{Chapter2/Figs/tikz/single_quadrant_switch}
```

This is the error from the log file

```
(./Chapter2/Figs/tikz/single_quadrant_switch.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for 'standalone' class
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no v in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no v in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no w in font nullfont!
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
./Chapter2/Figs/tikz/single_quadrant_switch.tex:21: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.21 \end{tikzpicture}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

)
File: Chapter2/Figs/tikz/single_quadrant_switch.tex Graphic file (type tex)


./Chapter2/chapter2.tex:39: Package graphics Error: Division by 0.

See the graphics package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.39 ...Chapter2/Figs/tikz/single_quadrant_switch}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


./Chapter2/chapter2.tex:39: Package graphics Error: Division by 0.

See the graphics package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.39 ...Chapter2/Figs/tikz/single_quadrant_switch}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

./Chapter2/chapter2.tex:52: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\sf@endfloatbox ...gefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.52  \end{figure}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./Chapter2/chapter2.tex:52: Too many }'s.
\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup 

l.52  \end{figure}

You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.


./Chapter2/chapter2.tex:52: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.52  \end{figure}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

./Chapter2/chapter2.tex:52: Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.52  \end{figure}

Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
```

Interesting thing is also that a circuitikz picture works fine with the \includestandalone command.

Here is the code for circuitikz and works on 2017 version of TeX Live

> diodes_four_quadrant_switch.tex

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[americanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.9pt]
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]

  \draw(3,0) node [nigbt, scale=1.8, name=igbt1] {};

  \draw(0,0) to[D, name=D1] (3,3){}
  to[D, name=D2, invert] (6,0){}
  to[D, name=D3, invert] (3,-3){}
  to[D, name=D3] (0,0){};

  \draw (igbt1.C) to[short, -*] (3,3);
  \draw (igbt1.E) to[short, -*] (3,-3);
  \draw (0,0) to[short, *-] ++(-1,0);
  \draw (6,0) to[short, *-] ++(1,0);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

I’m not sure what could be the problem.

I’m adding a simple example to better see the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[subpreambles=false, obeyclassoptions=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}
Simple example.

\begin{figure}[htbp!]

    \includestandalone[width=0.45\textwidth]{Chapter2/Figs/tikz/single_quadrant_switch}

    \includestandalone[width=0.45\textwidth]{Chapter2/Figs/tikz/diodes_four_quadrant_switch}


  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I just figured out it has to do something with the parameter obeyclassoptions in standalone package. When it is set to true, I get the error in the new version of Tex Live 2017 (not the old one).   But when I set it to false everything works fine.

Comment: You are not showing how exactly you are including the picture in your main document. Make a *complete* example.

Comment: It works without the `obeyclassoptions=true` option. And it is probably caused in part by changes in the graphic drivers. You could make a bug report for standalone and hope that it adapts its code.

Comment: Alternatively, remove `tikz` from the options in the `standalone` class.

Comment: Note that a key difference between the figures is that only one contains text. The problem from the error concerns fonts.

Comment: Thank you, cfr, it must be some kind of bug as mentioned by Ulrike, I will just leave “obeyclassoptions=false” for now because it seems to fix my problem without side effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the `tikz` option for `standalone` class is the same as `multi=tikzpicture` and loading the `tikz` package. The `multi` option however creates a new page for every mentioned environment. A new page in `standalone` requires a new box and therefore group, which can cause problems if the page break is badly placed.

If you have only a single `tikzpicture` in your standalone file or an extended environment like `circuitikz` DON'T use `tikz` class option but simply load the `tikz` package yourself.

When you use `obeyclassoptions` the `standalone` *package* will try to apply all class options of the `standalone` files and therefore will wrap the `tikzpicture` inside `circuitikz` inside a box, which I guess is the source of your problem.

Comment: you saved my day